# Update a field related to the model linked by a hasOne relationship on Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, eloquent, entity-relationship, laravel-5.4

I have 2 tables, `person` and `physicalperson`. The person table is a general table, and the physicalperson is a specific person related to a human (because we can also have moralperson that represent a company). These two tables are linked by a OnetoOne relationship.

Table "person" :

```
id  |   name    |   comments    |   created_at
==============================================
1       Doe                         2017-03-30
2       Bar         Test            2017-04-05
```

Table "physicalperson" :

```
id  |   person_id   |   surname |   birth
==============================================
1       1               John        1990-07-31
2       2               Foo         1970-01-01
```

Now I set up my relations ships, saying that for 1 person I have maximum 1 physical person :

```
<?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class Person extends Model
    {
        public $timestamps = false;

        protected $table = 'person';    
        protected $primaryKey = 'id';

        public function physical()
        {
            return $this->hasOne('App\PhysicalPerson');
        }
    }
?>
```

I confirm, in selection, I get all the data I need by doing a :

```
<?php
    $person = Person::findOrFail(1);

    echo $person->physical->surname; // Prints John
    echo $person->name; // Prints Doe
?>
```

But when I try to update my person (and the associated physicalperson), I only managed to get the update for the person, and the physical seems to be ignored for an unknown reason :

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Person extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $table = 'person';    
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function physical()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\PhysicalPerson');
    }

    public static function put( $id, Request $request )
    {
        $person = self::findOrFail( $id );

        $person->name = $request->input('name');
        $person->physical->surname = $request->input('surname'); // Seems to be ignored

        $person->save();
    }
}
```

**Question**

Does anyone already managed to updated a model "in cascade" using the Eloquent relationships methods ?

Comment: Did you set an `onUpdate('cascade')` on the `person_id` foreign key in the migration schema for physicalperson?

Comment: Nope I will try it thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$person = self::findOrFail( $id );
 $physicalPersion = physicalperson::where('persion_id' , '=' , $id)->get() ;
    $person->name = $request->input('name');
    $physicalPersion->surname = $request->input('surname'); 
    $physicalPersion->save() ;
    $person->save();
```